# $x$ with the operations $x+x´=xx´$ vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

The set of all positive real numbers $x$ with the operations $x+x´=xx´$ and $kx=x^k$. Determine if this set is a vector space.

My book solutions claim this set is a vector space however axiom **4)(u+0=u)** seems to fail since $0+x=x+0=x\times 0=0$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That axiom says that there exists an element $o$ such that $o+x=x*o=x$ for all $x$. Looks like $o=1$ works. IOW you are using the wrong number as $o$.

Comment: Well, the zero element of that vector space must be $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that in a vector space, "$0$" doesn't usually refer to the number $0$ (in fact, note that the number $0$ isn't even an element of our set).  Rather, a set satisfies axiom 4 if there exists a vector $x_0$ such that $x + x_0 = x$ for all $x$ (and confusingly, it is common to label this vector as $0$).

In the context of the positive real numbers multiplication, we can take $x_0 = 1$, since we find that
$$
x + x_0 = x(1) = x
$$

Comment: So the $x_0$ does not need to be zero or vector $0$. I was confused because the book states "(4) There is a vector $0$ in $V $ called the zero vector such that $0+u=u+0=u$ for all $u$ in $V$" Is this definition wrong or incomplete. The book is "Elementary Linear Algebra by Howard Anton". Thanks for your reply!

Comment: The definition is correct and it's complete, but it's also confusing.  The vector which we call "a vector $0$ in $V$" is not necessarily the literal number $0$, nor is it necessarily an object whose entries are all $0$.  Its only defining characteristic is that, with respect to addition, we have $u + 0 = 0 + u = u$ for all $u$ in $V$.

Answer (score 1):

We can check all of the axioms. Let's use $*$ for the operation between vectors.

**Associativity:** $u*(v*w)=(u*v)*w$

In our case we need $u(vw)=(uv)w$ which is true.

**Commutativity**: $u*v=v*u$

In our case we need $uv=vu$ which is true.

**Identity:** $I * u = u* I$

In our case we need $Iu=uI$ and this is true for $I=1$.

**Inverse:** For every $u$, there is a $v$ with $u*v = I = v*u$

In our case we need $uv=1=vu$ and this is true for $v=\frac{1}{u}$

**Comparability:** For scalars $\lambda$ and $\mu$ we have $\lambda(\mu u)=(\lambda\mu) u$

In our case we need $\left(u^{\lambda}\right)^{\mu} = u^{\lambda \mu}$, which is true.

**Distributivity 1:** For scalar $\lambda$ and vectors $u$ and $v$ we need $\lambda(u*v) =\lambda u * \lambda v$

In our case we need $(uv)^\lambda = u^{\lambda}v^{\lambda}$ which is true.

**Distributivity 2:** For scalars $\lambda$ and $\mu$ and vector $v$ we need $(\lambda+\mu)u = \lambda u * \mu u$

In our case we need $u^{\lambda+\mu} = u^{\lambda}u^{\mu}$, which is true.